# How to deploy/insert the App in all the pages of SharePoint automatically?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have installed an app on SharePoint sites with the help of this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2015/11/20/automating-add-inapp-installation-to-sharepoint-sites-using-csom/.)

Now I need to deploy/insert this app on the SharePoint page with the trust automatically.